# Getting rid of `instanceof`

Tags: java, types, sprite, instanceof

In a sprite based game I'm writing, each field in a 2D grid contains a stack of sprites. Mostly the top one counts.

In the rules module of the game, I have a lot of code like this:

```
public boolean isGameWon(Board board) {
    for (Point point : board.getTargetPoints())
        if(!(board.getTopSpriteAt(point) instanceof Box))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

---

**Upadate:** `//Do something` counts if there is a `Box` on top of each `Target`. I don't see how that can be done with simply adding `doSomething()` to Sprite, unless `doSomething()` returns 1 if the sprite is a box, and 0 otherwise. (and that would be just the same as instanceof).

---

I know instanceof is considered harmful because it kills the idea of object oriented programming.

I'm however not sure how to fix the code in my case. Here are some thoughts I've had:

- I don't think it makes it any better to simple add a `isABox()` method to the `Sprite` interface.
- Would it help if `Box` was an interface, so other classes could get the same priviledge?
- Should I try to do something fancy like pattern matching / double dispatch, with visitor like patterns?
- Is it OK that the rules module work intimately with the types, simply because it is supposed to know their semantics anyway?
- Is the entire idea of a rules module strategy pattern flawed?
- It doesn't make sense to build the rules into the Sprites, as they would then all have to be changed when a new type is added.

I hope you have tried something similar and are able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: did you think about adding a method doSomthing() to the Interface Sprite and let every impleneting class provide an implementation for it ?

Comment: Consider that a grid of base-class references is not appropriate here, because you want to treat specific derived-classes specially.  (Basically, you're violating the [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I think you hit the nail, I just havent found other ways?

Comment: Maybe this is just a case of https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/when-polymorphism-fails And I should just be happy that the smell is isolated in the Rules class...

Comment: @Thomas, in this case to be or not to be a box is a feature identifying the component, so, in this case, an isABox() method is IMO a good solution.

Comment: @TomasNarros But say I have 10 types: "Box, Cat, Bottle, Human, Target..." which all interact in some way. Then I would be adding 110 new isType methods.

Comment: @Thomas: Please, check my answer to see if it could be of any help.

Comment: `instanceof` is not itself a violation of the LSP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`Instanceof`**: (Almost) Always Harmful

I took a look at all the answers to your post and tried to understand what you were doing. And I have come to the conclusion that `instanceof` is **exactly** what you want and your original code sample was fine.

You clarified that:

- You are **not** violating the Liskov substitution principle since none of the Box code invalidates the Sprite code.
- You are **not** forking the code with the response to `instanceof`. This is why people say instanceof is bad; because people do this:

  ```
  if(shape instanceof Circle) {
      area = Circle(shape).circleArea();
  } else if(shape instanceof Square) {
      area = Square(shape).squareArea();
  } else if(shape instanceof Triangle) {
      area = Triangle(shape).triangleArea();
  }
  ```

  This is the reason why people avoid instanceof. But this is not what you are doing.
- There is a **one-to-one** relationship between `Box` and winning the game (no other Sprites can win the game). So you are not in need of an additional "winner" sprite abstraction (because Boxes == Winners).
- You are simply **checking** the board to make sure that each top item *is* a Box. This is exactly what `instanceof` is designed to do.

Everyone else's answer (including my own) adds an additional mechanism for checking whether a Sprite is a Box. However they do not add any robustness. In fact you are taking features which are already supplied by the language and reimplementing them in your own code.

Tomas Narros argues that you should distinguish in your code between "semantic types" and "java types". I disagree. You have already established that you have a java type, `Box`, which subclasses `Sprite`. So you already have all the information that you need.

In my view, having a second independent mechanism which also reports "I am a Box", violates DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). This means not having two independent sources for the same piece of information. You now have to maintain an enum and a class structure.

The so-called "benefit" is the ability to pirouette around a keyword which fully fills the purpose, and is harmful when used in more harmful ways.

---

The golden rule is **Use your head**. Don't obey rules as hard fact. Question them, learn why they are there, and bend them when appropriate.

Comment: Great answer. I really appreciate it. What I'm gonna do is try the suntax/semantics split and see if enough difference shows up no to violate DRY. Or if I find myself confused about which kind of type to use over and over.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this answer - I was facing a similar problem and your explanation helped a lot.

Answer (score 8):

Use [polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html):

```
class Sprite {
    ..
    someMethod(){
    //do sprite
    }
    ..
}

class Box extends Sprite {
    ..
    @Overrides
    someMethod(){
    //do box
    }
    ..
}
```

So, you just need to call sprite.someMethod() in your example.

Comment: How about now? I don't see how `someMethod()` can be anything other than `int isABox()`?

Comment: How about `cnt += sprite.size();` or `getCount()` or `getSize()` size returns 0 for most sprites and 1 for a Box.

Comment: You can incapsulate your cnt variable and logic related to it into some class and transfer instance of that class to someMethod().

Comment: @PeterLawrey What would you write in the javadoc for that method? "getSize() returns 1 if the object is a box, 0 otherwise".

Comment: @Artem: I already incapsulated cnt and the logic into the Rules class, if that's what you mean?

Comment: @ThomasAhle The OP hopefully has a better idea of why the number of boxes are being counted and give it a more meaningful method name, and thus Javadoc. Perhaps the Box is the underlying cell so if its on top the cell is empty?? I suspect using meaningful method names would be helpful.

Comment: @PeterLawrey The game is about moving Boxes onto Targets. It seams inherent to the rules, that we want to test if the box objects are on the same cords as the target objects, and not if anything else is there..

Comment: @ThomasAhle In that case, `if(sprite.isABox()) cnt++;` may be the clearest, but its not clear why you are comparing the count with the size.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: OK, you are right that `isABox()` would solve the strong dependence on the syntactic types. However it won't solve the strong dependence on the types in general. I would have to add `isAHuman()`, `isATarget()`, `isSomeType()` for every type I create, if I want any rules linked to it. The code in `Rules` would be nearly the same, but the `Sprite` types would be filled with trivial tests..

Answer (score 3):

Basic overloading is the way to go here. It's the Sprite class hierarchy that should know what to do and how to do it, as in:

```
interface Sprite {
    boolean isCountable();
}


class MyOtherSprite implements Sprite {
    boolean isCountable() {
        return false;
    }
 }

 class Box implements Sprite {
    boolean isCountable() {
        return true;
    }
}

int count = 0;
for (Point point : board.getTargetPoints()) {
    Sprite sprite = board.getTopSpriteAt(point);
    count += sprite.isCountable() ? 1 : 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Your edit to the question does not fundamentally change the problem. What you have is some logic that is only applicable to `Box`. Again, encapsulate that particular logic in the `Box` instance (see above). You could go further and create a generic superclass for your sprites that defines a default value for `isCountable()` (note that the method is similar to the isBox one but is actually better from a design perspective, since it makes no sense for a Circle to have a isBox method - should Box also contain a isCircle method?).

Answer (score 3):

Here is my try. Consider defining an enum with the different Sprite types:

```
class Sprite {
    public enum SpriteType {
         BOX, CAT, BOTTLE, HUMAN, TARGET, /* ... */, SIMPLE;
    }

    public SpriteType getSpriteType(){
       return SIMPLE;
    }
}


class Box extends Sprite {
    @Override
    public SpriteType getSpriteType(){
       return Sprite.SpriteType.BOX;
    }
}
```

And at last:

```
public boolean isGameWon(Board board) {
    for (Point point : board.getTargetPoints())
        if(board.getTopSpriteAt(point).getSpriteType()!=SpriteType.BOX)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

This way, you can solve the problem of having to create an isATypeX() method in Sprite for every type X.
If you need a new type, you add a new value to the enum, and only the rule who need to check this type will need to aknowledge it.

Comment: Good try. This is nice because the enums play the role as semantic identifiers in the eyes of `Rules`, which in some way separates the semantics from the types. But does it really give anything to the code in terms of maintainability? I'll need to think about this one for a bit :)

Comment: I think it will, as to create a new type only affects the enum, the type itself, and the rules to apply.

Comment: That's still one more than just using the class type as the semantic type as well ;)

Comment: I think this violates DRY. The information is already in the class structure, no need to repeat it in an enum.

Comment: @Chris: not necesary. Some descending classes could just return the default value, other clases could use the same (i.e. classes Man and Woman returning PERSON). Actually, with the enum you are isolating the "semantic type" from the "java type", IMO

Comment: It still violates DRY unless the enum *adds* information. (Whereas returning PERSON would be *removing* information.) All you are doing is adding an additional type system into the codebase, increasing confusion, and the possibility for mistakes.

Comment: Hm, the enum system has the disadvantage compared to classes that it's harder to make hierarchies/groupings.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, instead of

```
if (sprite instanceof Box)
    // Do something
```

Use

```
sprite.doSomething()
```

where `doSomething()` is defined in in `Sprite` and overriden in `Box`.

If you want these rules separated from the Sprite class hierarchy, you can move them to a separate `Rules` class (or interface), where `Sprite` has a `getRules()` method and subclasses return different implementations. This would further increase flexibility, as it allows objects of the same `Sprite` subclass to have different behaviour.

Comment: How would you implement the test "Is there a box on every target" using rules kept within sprites?

Comment: @Thomas Ahle: `cnt += sprite.getTargetCount()`, where `getTargetCount()` returns 1 in `Box`  and 0 in ' Sprite`. There may be cleaner solutions, but that comes to mind immediately. And no, that's not at all the same as having an instanceof test in the code that does the counting.

Comment: I know where you want to go, but how would you describe that method in the docs? "Return 1 if you are a Box, 0 otherwise?". It might not be the same as "instanceof", but how is it any better?

Comment: @Thomas Ahle: No, it should absolutely not be called that. It should apply to (and be named for) that specific behaviour of Boxes. The important thing is that the check now has a domain-specific name and is located in the type itself (or a rules class specific to that type). If you add a new class that behaves like a Box but should not be counted when on top of a Target, that class can have a different implementation of that one method.

Comment: @Thomas Ahle: "Return 1 if this object should count towards ??? if it's on top of a Target, 0 otherwise"

Comment: OK, so something like "Returns true if this object can be placed on a target (or something that counts as a target) to solve the game". And of course then it would have to be in a `getRules()` method because the sprites are not rule dependent. ; But in reality I would still end up adding methods `countsAsATypeX` for every type X I create?

Comment: @Thomas Ahle: No - the point is that you create one method for every specific piece of behaviour that differs between types, and where possible those methods should contain actual logic rather than just returning constants.

Comment: Right, but the thing is that the sprites don't have behavior in them selves, but only in connection with other types. If I was to move the logic into them, they would still need to do type tests, and every one would need to be edited each time a new type was added.

Comment: @Thomas Ahle: It should not be necessary to edit every type, unless every new type actually interacts *differently* with every single existing type. I'd expect that you's generally only add methods that implement the new behaviour in a default way to the base Sprite class and override it only where there's actually a difference. But going into more detail probably exceeds the scope here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a generic counter without an isAnX() method for each type you might want to count.  Say you want to count number of type X on the board.

```
public int count(Class type) {
    int count = 0;
    for (Point point : board.getTargetPoints())
        if(type.isAssignable(board.getTopSpriteAt(point)))
            count++;
    return count;
}
```

---

I suspect what you really want is

```
public boolean isAllBoxes() {
    for (Point point : board.getTargetPoints())
        if(!board.getTopSpriteAt(point).isABox())
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, that's much cleaner :) It still doesn't solve the problem of having to create an `isATypeX()` method in `Sprite` for every type X that I create (and the rules need to know of).

Comment: @ThomasAhle Perhaps the counting example I have given avoids the need for lots of `isAnXxx()` methods.

Comment: And then in my Rules I would have `boolean isGameWon(Board board){return count(Box.class) == board.getTargetPoints();}`?

Comment: You could but it would be less efficient as it will always count every Point even if the first is not a box.

Answer (score 1):

What you are really testing for here is,

> Can the player **win the game** with this `Sprite` at the top of the board?

Therefore, I suggest these names:

```
public boolean isGameWon(Board board) {
    for (Point point : board.getTargetPoints())
        if(!board.getTopSpriteAt(point).isWinningSprite())
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

There is absolutely no point in having an `isBox` function. None whatsoever. You might as well use `instanceof`.

But if `Box`, `Bottle` and `Target` are all winning tiles, then you can have them all return

```
class Box {
    public override bool isWinningSprite() { return true; }
}
```

You can then add another type of "winning" sprite without altering the `isGameWon` function.

Comment: ps I am not 100% about the `isWinningSprite` name, there may be a better name depending on what the game is you are making.

Comment: I agree with you, but actually this is what Tomas Narros answer is about too. The enum type "Box" could just as well be called the "winning sprite". It's meaning is only in the eyes of the rules. What is important is to difference between class-types and rule-types.

Comment: @Thomas: If there is no possibility of any other sprites being a winning sprite, other than Boxes, then I believe that the cleanest, most maintainable solution might be to use `instanceof`.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a visitor.

Every points inherits the acceptBoxDetection method:

```
boolean acceptBoxDetection(Visitor boxDetector){
           return boxDetector.visit(this);
}

and then Visitor does:

boolean visit(Box box){
        return true;
}

boolean visit(OtherStuff other){
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

General statements about object-oriented design / refactorings are hard to give IMHO as the "best" action depends on the context very much.

You should try moving the "Do something" into a virtual method of Sprite which does nothing. This method can be called from within your loop.

Box can then override it and do the "something".

Answer (score 0):

I think what people suggested to you is correct. Your `doSomething()` can look like this:

```
class Sprite {
    public int doSomething(int cnt){
       return cnt;
    }
}

class Box extends Sprite {
    @Override
    public int doSomething(int cnt){
       return cnt + 1;
    }
}
```

So in your original code, you can do this:

```
int cnt = 0;
for (Point point : board.getTargetPoints()) {
    Sprite sprite = board.getTopSpriteAt(point)
    cnt = sprite.doSomething(cnt);
}
```

Or else, you can also achieve the same goal with what you suggested but it may cost an additional calculation per loop.

```
class Sprite {
    public boolean isBox() {
        return false;
    }
}

class Box extends Sprite {
    @Override
    public boolean isBox(){
       return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: But this is exactly the same as having a `boolean isBox()` in Sprite, which is exactly the same as having `instanceof Box`.. I suppose the problem here is in the preconditions where I want to know something about Boxes and Targets. This is syntax rather than semantics and violates that Liskov principle. I just don't know what else to do?

Comment: Well, it's not exactly the same. If you override the method `doSomething` in Box, when you execute that method from any Sprite object which is a Box, it will trigger the method inside the Box class instead. You don't need an additional calculation for `isBox()` or `instanceof`. Besides, you are not violating Liskov rule if you override the `doSomething` method.

Comment: Liskov substitution principle says that `if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S without altering any of the desirable properties of that program (correctness, task performed, etc.)`. The `desirable properties` of your program is to increment `cnt` if and only if the `Sprite` is a `Box`. So if you substitute all your `Sprite` with its subclass and you still get the same `desirable properties`, you're not violating Liskov principle.

Comment: Ok, I see this might solve the problem on relying on specific implementations. But it would mean that for every new Sprite type I created, I would have to add a `isNewType()` method to `Sprite` and every other implementation..

Comment: @ThomasAhle yeah. Hence, I think it might be better if you override `doSomething`.

Comment: With `doSomething`, you don't need to add `isNewType()` to `Sprite` every time you have a new `Type` of `Sprite`. Besides, as I mentioned, it may save you 1 additional calculation per loop. Imagine if you have `Box`, `Bottle` & `Can` extend `Sprite`, you will need 3 `isBox()`, `isBottle()`, `isCan()` inside your loop.

Comment: My point was that what `doSomething` would do here is testing whether the object is a `Box`. That's the only thing that needs to be done in the loop. With an `isType` for every subtype of sprite, I end up with n^2 extra methods..

Answer (score -1):

When you say 'stack' and 'the top one counts', could you not just take the top one and do something with it?

Comment: That's what `getTopSpriteAt` does. Takes something from the top of the stack. I just added it there, because it might be useful in a pattern matching solution.

Comment: Oops, my fault. Well, I suggest going with @Artems answer.